# JSF update inputText after selectOneMenu choice

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I want to change the inputTexts' values when I choose another Skin from my selectOneMenu. 
Everything is doing well, my Converter gives back the right Object from the menu, but the inputTexts are not updated.

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="dropdownSkin"
        value="#{helloBean.currentSkin}" defaultLabel="Select a skin.."
        valueChangeListener="#{helloBean.skinValueChanged}" immediate="true"
        onchange="this.form.submit()" converter="SkinConverter" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.mySkinsSI}" var="c"
            itemValue="#{c.value}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>


    <br />
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.title}"></h:inputText>
    <br />
    <h:inputText id="tcolor" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.titleBar.textColor}"></h:inputText>
    <br />
    <h:inputText id="bcolor" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.titleBar.backgroundColorStart}"></h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

Here is what my Bean looks like. I debugged it and the Object currentSkin is set correctly. Now i need to know how to update the textfields content.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<ExtendedSkin> mySkins;
private List<SelectItem> mySkinsSI;
private ExtendedSkin currentSkin;

public void skinValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    currentSkin = (ExtendedSkin) e.getNewValue();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}

public List<ExtendedSkin> getMySkins() {
    mySkins = XMLParser.readExtendedSkins();
    return mySkins;
}

public List<SelectItem> getMySkinsSI() {
    mySkinsSI = new LinkedList<SelectItem>();
    for (ExtendedSkin s : getMySkins()) {
        mySkinsSI.add(new SelectItem(s, s.getTitle()));
    }
    return mySkinsSI;
}

public void setMySkinsSI(List<SelectItem> myItems) {
    this.mySkinsSI = myItems;
}

public ExtendedSkin getCurrentSkin() {
    if (currentSkin == null) {
        currentSkin = getMySkins().get(0);
    }
    return currentSkin;
}

public void setCurrentSkin(ExtendedSkin currentSkin) {
    this.currentSkin = currentSkin;
}
}
```

Comment: Try moving the `<h:inputText>`s outside the form (as a 1st try). That should work

Comment: Omg u did it thx :) Post it as answer so i can accept it ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain the problem and the possible solutions. The one I've provided in my comment is just one.

Comment: okay, later on I guess I have to put the inputTexts into a form again, beacuse i will have to make a preview with the values from the textes, maybe you could try to make that work too ;)

Comment: Hope my answer clears some concepts to you and show advantages of using JSF 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the converter is doing its work filling the `helloBean.currentSkin` object, but the values in the `<h:inputText>` that are bounded to this `helloBean.currentSkin`: `title`, `textColor` and `backgroundColorStart` will be send to the server and replace the actual values that were loaded by the `converter`. In other words:

- The converter is executed and builds the `helloBean.currentSkin` based on the selected value.
- The `<h:inputText id="name">` empty value is sent to server and will be injected in `helloBean.currentSkin.title`. Same behavior for the other 2 `<h:inputText>`s.
- The view will be loaded using the selected `helloBean.currentSkin` and it will load the `helloBean.currentSkin.title` with the empty value. Same behavior for the other 2 `<h:inputText>`s.

There are two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Move the `<h:inputText>`s outside the form, so the empty values won't be send to the server. When loading the view, it will maintain the values loaded in the converter.

   ```html
   <h:form>
       <h:selectOneMenu id="dropdownSkin"
           value="#{helloBean.currentSkin}" defaultLabel="Select a skin.."
           valueChangeListener="#{helloBean.skinValueChanged}" immediate="true"
           onchange="this.form.submit()" converter="SkinConverter" >
           <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.mySkinsSI}" var="c"
               itemValue="#{c.value}" />
       </h:selectOneMenu>
   </h:form>
   <br />
   <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.title}"></h:inputText>
   <!-- rest of Facelets code... -->
   ```
2. Since you're loading the `helloBean.currentSkin` while changing the selected value on your dropdownlist, you can add ajax behavior using [`<f:ajax>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html) tag component inside the `<h:selectOneMenu>` and update the fields in a cleaner way. I would opt for this solution.

   ```html
   <h:form>
       <!-- Note that there's no need of the onchange JavaScript function -->
       <h:selectOneMenu id="dropdownSkin"
           value="#{helloBean.currentSkin}" defaultLabel="Select a skin.."
           valueChangeListener="#{helloBean.skinValueChanged}" immediate="true"
           converter="SkinConverter" >
           <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.mySkinsSI}" var="c"
               itemValue="#{c.value}" />
           <f:ajax process="@this" render="name tcolor bcolor" />
       </h:selectOneMenu>
       <br />
       <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.title}" />
       <h:inputText id="tcolor" value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.titleBar.textColor}" />
       <br />
       <h:inputText id="bcolor"
           value="#{helloBean.currentSkin.titleBar.backgroundColorStart}" />
   </h:form>
   ```

You can learn more about `<f:ajax>` in online tutorial like [this one](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/).

Since you're going to use an ajax call in your page, you should change your managed bean scope from `@SessionScoped` to `@ViewScoped`. More info about this here: [Communication in JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Comment: This answer helped me solve my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182423/change-input-based-on-combo-value/