# Change input based on combo value

Tags: jsf-2

I know this question exists somewhere else in SO but either the solutions are old (and JSF seems to have improved a lot) or I cannot make the solution work.

As simple as it sounds, I would like to replace the text of an input element based on the value of a combo box. I would like to use Ajax, and would like this to work even if there is only one element in the combo (it doesn't matter if by default the selection of the combo is empty).

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="fnamecombo" valueChangeListener="#{namesController.setForename(fnamecombo)}">
    <c:forEach items="#{namesController.myForenames}" var="myforename">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{myforename}" itemLabel="#{myforename}" />
    </c:forEach>
    <f:ajax render="fnameinput"  />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText value="#{namesController.forename}" id="fnameinput" />
```

This doesn't work. So first of all, I have no idea how to call the `setForename` method. If I use `valueChangeListener="#{namesController.setForename('xxxxx')}"` it works, but only the 1st time and iff there are more than one element in the combo, since otherwise the event does not seem to be fired.

What is the easy fix?

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so I have made progress. It was easier than I expected:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="fnamecombo" value="#{namesController.forename}">
    <c:forEach items="#{namesController.myForenames}" var="myforename">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{myforename}" itemLabel="#{myforename}" />
    </c:forEach>
    <f:ajax render="fnameinput"  />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText value="#{namesController.forename}" id="fnameinput" />
```

This seems to work on a `selectItem` that I create by hand, but not on the one that is printing with the `foreach` loop. So this is the rendered code, where I obtained 'john' from the loop and I manually created 'example':

```
<select id="myForm:fnamecombo" name="myForm:fnamecombo" size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'myForm:fnameinput')">
    <option value="example">example</option>
    <option value="john">john</option>
</select>
```

It works with 'example' but not with 'john'.

Comment: You can use f:selectItems instead of c:forEach

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.. What do you mean? And how this solve the problem?

Comment: OK, now I understand what you said. I have changed c:forEach to f:selectedItems, but still the values are not obtained. Only if I put the selectItem manually it seems to work with them. With the f:selectedItems only deletes the input field. Because the generated code is the same for all options, there must be something else I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="fnamecombo" value="#{namesController.forename}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{namesController.myForenames}" />
    <f:ajax render="fnameinput"  />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText value="#{namesController.forename}" id="fnameinput" />
```

No need for `forEach` as mentioned by Alexandre Lavoie.

[This answer by Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024183/jsf-update-inputtext-after-selectonemenu-choice) gave me the hint to find it out. The reason my input was not updated by the values in the `f:selectItems` and it was in the ones that I introduced manually is the scope of the managed bean. I realised that the `input` was actually being updated in any case, but when coming from the `f:selectItems` the `input` was updated with `null`. Why? Because the scope of `namesController` was `@RequestScoped` and not `@ViewScoped`. Changing this solves the problem.